# Spotfire COM Automation

Tags: c#, com, spotfire

I am trying to automate save to library using COM object of spotfire. I looked at the examples of Spotfire SDK for COM automation, it calls OpenDocument method using InvokeMethod. When I try to call Save method using the same technique it throws me Missing Member Exception.

```
    public bool OpenDocument(string filePath)
    {
        var test = this.InvokeMethod("OpenDocument", filePath);

        return (bool)test;
    }

    public bool SaveDocument()
    {            
        return (bool)this.InvokeMethod("Save", null);    

    }
```

In the above code snippet, OpenDocument is working perfectly fine but Its throwing error for Save. The com object is of System.__comobject type so I am not even able to inspect and get the metadata (methods / properties) to see the actual method name, which I can use as a parameter to InvokeMethod

Comment: Please, please, please show us your code.

Comment: I can email you the complete code. Meanwhile if you can let me know how to get the members or metadata of System.__comobject would solve my problem.

Comment: The code is supposed to go in the question.  This is a programming Q&A site, we answer  questions about code, we cant fix problems without code, the code should go in the question, i don't want you to send it to me, please put it in your question.

Comment: Have you looked up their documentation to see if they have a OpenDocument method?

Comment: I checked the documentation, the dll has Open, Save method. There is no method as OpenDocument, but passing OpenDocument as a parameter to InvokeMethod somehow does the job. This was the example code provided by Tibco Spotfire, so I went ahead and added the same for calling the Save method but its not working.

Comment: I'm not sure of the syntax, but it most likely returns a VARIANT. That's why I think the example has var test and later it casts as boolean to return. Did you try that? Also, it can be that the name of the command be SaveDocument instead of Save. The documentation should tell you the exact names to use, because there is no similarity for COM calls.Also, why the last null parameter?

Comment: @Carlos Thank you for the reply. Is there any way by which we can get the metadata of System.__comobject as the com object is of that type, I am not able to get the actual com type.

Comment: @Prabhakar I don't know how to do that in C#. You can try to see the type LIb if there is one. Try to examine the tlib file or the dll with the tools of your IDE. Or just contact the vendor of Spotfire and ask it. You could also try navigating the TYPEINFO (if it is provided), with this.GetTypeInfo(0), but you would require to read more about that.

Comment: @Carlos Thank you. I have already raised a service request with the vendor. It was bit urgent so thought of asking here.

Comment: @Carlos Thank you. I have already raised a service request with the vendor. It was bit urgent so thought of asking here.